# Multiple constructor functions - Will they be executed once?

Tags: solidity, constructor

let's say I have the following contract/solidity file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract partOne {
    address public owner;
    function partOne() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract partTwo is partOne{
    uint public ownerBalance;
    function partTwo() public {
        ownerBalance = 500;
    }
}
```

Now, constructor functions are runned once and only in the contract deployment. Will now both constructor functions run once and after that not being callable again? Or is it better to put everything in the second constructor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy `partOne` its constructor will be called once. 
When you deploy `partTwo` the `partOne`'s constructor will be invoked before the `partTwo`'s one both only once.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to have constructor in parent contract. It will be expecuted once, on deployment.

According to last solidity style guides - it is better to use `constructor() {}` instead of `function partOne() {}`.

Comment: I know that constructor is recommended to use. My question was only, if in my case both functions are runned only once.